# regex_match doesn't find any matching

Tags: c++, regex

I tested the RegEx `[BCGRYWbcgryw]{4}\[\d\]` on that [site](http://regexpal.com/) and it seems ok to find match in the following **BBCC[0].GGRY[0].WWWW[soln]**. It match with **BBCC[0]**  and **GGRY[0]**.

But when I tried to code and debug that matching, the `sm`value stay empty.

```
    regex r("[BCGRYWbcgryw]{4}\\[\\d\\]");
string line; in >> line;
smatch sm;
regex_match(line, sm, r, regex_constants::match_any);
copy(boost::begin(sm), boost::end(sm), ostream_iterator<smatch::value_type>(cout, ", "));
```

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Which compiler?  Last time I checked GCC does not support C++11 regex yet.

Comment: Supported since October: http://gcc.gnu.org/

Comment: I used to build with VS'2012

Comment: did you try whith a simple quote version and [:digit:] in place of \d ?

Comment: @BoBTFish:  Do you know if that version of libstdc++v3 comes with GCC 4.8.2 release or with the 4.9 development series?

Comment: I tested your code out on VS2010 and it seems to work just fine. But perhaps this will work too:

    regex r("[BCGRYWbcgryw]{4}\\[[0-9]\\]");

Comment: It looks like regex_match match the whole string, so search/capture data in a string that match with a regex, the best way is to use the regex_iterator, see my answer

Comment: @JoeZ, it's only supported in GCC 4.9, which will probably be released around April

Comment: @JonathanWakely:  Ok, that's what I thought:  It's not supported in a released version of GCC yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to match the whole input sequence then use `std::regex_search` not `std::regex_match`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  regex r(R"([BCGRYWbcgryw]{4}\[\d\])");
  string line = "BBCC[0].GGRY[0].WWWW[soln]";
  smatch sm;
  regex_search(line, sm, r, regex_constants::match_any);
  copy(std::begin(sm), std::end(sm), ostream_iterator<smatch::value_type>(cout, ", "));
  cout << endl;
}
```

N.B. this also uses raw strings to simplify the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

I finally get it work, with `()` to define a capture group and I use `regex_iterator` to find all sub-string matching  the pattern.

```
std::regex rstd("(\\[[0-9]\\]\.[BCGRYWbcgryw]{4})");
std::sregex_iterator stIterstd(line.begin(), line.end(), rstd);
std::sregex_iterator endIterstd;

for (stIterstd; stIterstd != endIterstd; ++stIterstd)
{
    cout << " Whole string " << (*stIterstd)[0] << endl;
    cout << " First sub-group " << (*stIterstd)[1] << endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
Whole string [0].GGRY
First sub-group [0].GGRY
Whole string [0].WWWW
First sub-group [0].WWWW
```